# How to detect an image file is actually an image file not coded file in php?

Tags: php

How to detect an image file's original extention.Suppose the user uploaded a file with extention 'jpg' and that is a successful operation;because jpg is a supported format. Now if the user write a php file with hacking codes and rename the file as extention 'jpg'.  Now how to prevent the user from making me fool.

Comment: didn't find anything in Google? am sure there are a lot of Q&A's for this

Comment: Fred,  can you please answer me with efficient code.  or just give me the link of the question which is already answered.

Comment: what're you telling me for? you should be pointing that to the guy who gave you an answer man. See the link the question's been closed with.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [getimagesize](http://www.php.net/getimagesize)(), it will return 0 if it is not an image.

Comment: *Please don't drink/text and drive*.

Comment: @Fred-ii- How high are you? .. err I mean: Hi, how are you ?

Comment: *hic!* - oops, pardon me. I'm flying, I mean I'm fine, e tu? @MajidLaissi

Comment: si señor.. I need a drink :(

Comment: @MajidLaissi Time for you to go to the "Foo baz" **bar** then ;-) or "salad" bar.

Comment: must be cold in there..